# SQL Server table index - performance issues

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I'm using SQL Server for my web application database source with the main transaction table below:

[image]

OrderID is the primary key and it's an identity column.

This table contains a large number of rows, and is often used for queries for analytics and dashboard summary for the users.

Summary per Year, Region, User, and Status are the usual reports shown to the user's Dashboard Page.

[image]

I often use the `Year, Region, User` columns for my queries to load data for the users and would like to know how can I improve the data fetch performance using an index on this table.

Comment: well, it depends on how you use those fields. do you always query by Year, Region and user in that order, in which case you could create just one index. 
however, if you query bu any of those fields in any order you will require multiple indexes.

Comment: A Nonclustered Index for those columns that I usually used for queries?

Comment: what's the current clustered index that you have on it? is it being used for scans/seeks?

Comment: "It depends" is the case here. You're interested in covering indexes here. So if your queries typically use Year, or they use Region, or they use User, or they use Status then separate indexes for each of those columns would work best. If they typically use Year, Region, User and Status together then a single index with those columns would work better - ensuring that you rank the column indexes by decreasing uniqueness. Read up on how SQL Server uses [Cardinality Estimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/cardinality-estimation-sql-server).

Comment: Currently, OrderID (PrimaryKey) only has Index

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. And for a performance question please post a query and associated execution plan.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). This applies to data as well. Images of that data are not useful, as the data cannot be copied/pasted to use to create test tables. The images are also useless to those people using mobile devices such as smartphones that have limited screen space.

Comment: As has been mentioned, it depends on your queries. If you select data for a particular year and then show counts and sums per user, you want an index on `(year, userid`); If you select data for a particular user and then show counts and sums per year, you want an index on `(userid, year`). Just to give you an example :-) In the end you will create a bunch of indexes that cover the most typical queries.

Comment: Is it ok to have multiple indexes like below? Year, Cycle, UserID, Region, Year & Cycle, Year & Cycle & Region